CreateRoom failed Photon Network
I'm trying to create a room using Photon PUN, but I'm getting an error:

CreateRoom failed. Client is on MasterServer (must be Master Server for matchmaking) but not ready for operations (State: PeerCreated). Wait for callback: OnJoinedLobby or OnConnectedToMaster.

Here's the line where this error appears:
PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(string.Format("[PUBLIC MATCH] {0}", 
    PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber + Random.Range(0, 999)),
    new RoomOptions() { 
        MaxPlayers = (byte)maxPlayers, 
        IsVisible = false, 
        IsOpen = false,
        CustomRoomProperties = roomOption,
        CleanupCacheOnLeave = true,
        CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby = properties
    },
    null);

What's the cause of this error?

This error happens when you try to create a room before Unity fully connects to Photon, or while it's doing something else (like already trying to join a room).
To fix this, make sure that you only ever call this function whenever the client is actually connected, either by checking PhotonNetwork.IsConnectedAndReady, or, if you want the player to join a room automatically when the game starts, you can use the OnConnectedToMaster callback:
Make sure your class inherits from MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks, override the OnConnectedToMaster method, and put your room creation code into the method:
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks {

  public override void OnConnectedToMaster() {

    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(string.Format("[PUBLIC MATCH] {0}", 
        PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber + Random.Range(0, 999)),
          new RoomOptions() { 
            MaxPlayers = (byte)maxPlayers, 
            IsVisible = false, 
            IsOpen = false,
            CustomRoomProperties = roomOption,
            CleanupCacheOnLeave = true,
            CustomRoomPropertiesForLobby = properties
        },
        null);
  }

  // ... rest of your class' code...
}

